# Работа с массивом $_SESSION

Tags: php, sql

Можно ли использовать инструкцию echo внутри массива $_SESSION? Нужно, чтобы каждый элемент массива имел уникальное имя.

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `players` WHERE `fio` LIKE '%$query%' ");

                if (mysqli_num_rows ($result) > 0) {

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    ?>
     <img src="players_photo/<?php echo $row['player_photo'] ?> " align="left" width="100"; style="margin-right: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px">
            <span style="font-weight: bold;">
                <?php
    echo '<br>'.$row['fio'];
    $_SESSION['player_id'] = $row['id'];
    ?>
     <br clear="left">
    </span>

   <form action="#" method="POST">
    <button type="submit" name="query_button1" class="b2">Добавить</button>
</form>
  <?php
}
  }
```

Обработчик кнопки.

```
if( isset($_POST['query_button1']) ){
    $errors = array();
    $login = $_SESSION['id'];
    $id= $_SESSION['player_id'];


$result2 = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM subscription_players WHERE user_id ='$login' AND player_id = '$id' ");
    $myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
    if (!empty($myrow['id'])) {
        $errors[]= 'Введённая вами категория уже добавлена.';
    }
        else{
    $result = mysqli_query ($connection, "INSERT INTO subscription_players (user_id, player_id) VALUES('$login','$id')");
}
}
```

Comment: а `echo` тут причем? Что конкретно хотите сделать опишите и мы вам поможем конкретно.

Comment: Есть цикл, который присваивает массиву $_SESSION значения из базы данных. Используя функцию mysqli_fetch_assoc() я извлекаю найденные значения и присваиваю их массиву. В итоге у меня получатся, что массив  $_SESSION хранит только последнее значение, которое ему присвоили. Он перезаписывает их, а мне нужно получить доступ ко всем переменным.

Comment: покажите код присваивания.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        ?>
        <img src="players_photo/<?php echo $row['player_photo'] ?> " align="left" width="100"; style="margin-right: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px">
        <span style="font-weight: bold;">
            <?php
            echo '<br>' . $row['fio'];
            $_SESSION['player_id'] = $row['id'];
            ?>
            <br clear="left">
        </span>

        <form action="#" method="POST">
            <button type="submit" name="query_button1" class="b2">Добавить</button>
        </form>
        <?php
    }
}
```

заменяем на:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        ?>
        <img src="players_photo/<?php echo $row['player_photo'] ?> " align="left" width="100"; style="margin-right: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px">
        <span style="font-weight: bold;">
            <?php
            echo '<br>' . $row['fio'];
            ?>
            <br clear="left">
        </span>

        <form action="#" method="POST">
            <input name="player_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
            <button type="submit" name="query_button1" class="b2">Добавить</button>
        </form>
        <?php
    }
}
```

**в обработчике:**

```
if( isset($_POST['query_button1']) ){
    $errors = array();
    $login = $_SESSION['id'];
    $id= $_SESSION['player_id'];
```

заменяем на:

```
if( isset($_POST['query_button1']) ){
    $errors = array();
    $login = $_SESSION['id'];
    if (filter_var($_POST['player_id'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) !== false) {
        $id = $_POST['player_id'];
    }else{
        // Ошибка
    }
```

Comment: То, что нужно. Спасибо!